# Openrowset in Stored Procedure giving transport-level error

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UploadExcel
    @Path VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX);
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
          ''Excel 12.0; Database='+@Path+''',[Data$]);';
        EXEC (@sql);
    END
GO

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1

EXEC sp_UploadExcel @Path = 'path\file.xlsx'
```

Getting

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
> server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has
> been ended.)

and service stops

If needed here is the connection string:

> Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVER02;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;

Been stuck at this for hours, any info will be appreciated

Comment: Strongly consider redoing this approach in client-side code that just bulk inserts to tables.  That also gives ample opportunity for detecting/fixing problems with data in the sheets (of which you can expect plenty if the sheets are uploaded by people). As you've discovered, troubleshooting this stuff when it's done directly through the engine is far from simple.

Comment: This is what SSIS and BCP is for